# Error when getting original images from Hadoop sequenceFile

Tags: image, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sequencefile

I first pack all my images into Hadoop sequenceFile:

```
FSDataInputStream in = null;    
in = fs.open(new Path(uri)); //uri is the image location in HDFS
byte buffer[] = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(buffer);
context.write(imageID, new BytesWritable(buffer));
```

Then I want to get my original images back from Sequence file, in the reducer:

```
BufferedImage imag;    
imag = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes()));
```

But the image is not properly got, since I have this error:

```
Error: javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

My question is how to get original images from sequence file in hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I use the wrong way to read the stream. Here is the right way.:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
Configuration confHadoop = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(confHadoop);
Path file = new Path(fs.getUri().toString() + "/" + fileName);
in = fs.open(file);
byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

Then the buffer can be written to sequenceFile by `new BytesWritable(buffer)`.
Same when you read from the sequenceFile.